# How to visit page with login user, rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm a beginer in ruby on rail and i'm trying to use rspec to check my controller. But i have some trouble to visit my page in spec.
Here is my user_spec.rb:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'user'
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  it "login sucess" do
    visit "welcome/index"
    fill_in "session_user_id", :with => "1992111-1234"
    fill_in "session_password", :with => "sa1234"
    click_button "ログイン"   
  end

  it "main menu" do
    visit "welcome/mainmenu"
  end
end
```

When I run spec, I have this error:
[image]

I can't pass through shop_no because i dont have current_user: `<%= current_user.shop_no%>`. So, i must login user first, but i don't know how to work with rspec. I tried to creat login(user) in my spec/user.rb:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require "rails_helper"

  def login(user)
    visit root_path
    fill_in "session_user_id", :with => "1992111-1234"
    fill_in "session_password", :with => "sa1234"
    click_button "ログイン"
  end
```

But i don't know how to work with that. So, please help me !

Update login page:

```
<div class="medium-4 medium-centered row" style="padding: 5px">
    <div class="medium-10 medium-centered columns">
        <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <div class="notice">
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label(:User_id, 'User ID') %>
        <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
        <%= f.label :Password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <center>
            <%= f.submit "ログイン", class: "button [tiny large]", :style => "border-radius: 0px 0px" %>
        </center>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that your error in `app/views/welcome/mainmenu.html.erb` so Please post `app/views/welcome/mainmenu.html.erb`

Comment: in that view there may be a method call shop_no which is not defined please check that also

Comment: @Rajarshi Das,I added my mainmenu and i call shop_no in <%= current_user.shop_no%>. So i think i must login first in spec

Comment: yes it did not understand `current_user`

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways but this should work. It effectively logs the user in for every test. You might have to add code to log out the user before the next test.

Change `it "login success" do` to this line:

```
describe User do
  before :each do   # <===== this line
    visit "welcome/index"
    fill_in "user_id", :with => "1992111-1234"  # <=== updated
    fill_in "password", :with => "sa1234"       # <=== updated
    click_button "ログイン"
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Can you check the error again ? Is it still `undefined 'shop_no' for nil:NilClass` ?

Comment: Yeah! because my current_user in <%= current_user.shop_no%> was nil. So i must to keep login(current_user) in index page to mainmenu page

Comment: The `before :each do ... end` should have logged in the user and  therefore `current_user` wouldn't be nil. The error means that current_user is nil, which should mean that the login has failed.

Comment: I think you right! I updatded my question with login page, please! see it. Can you help me to find what problem in my code?